# How to loop them out?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

If the structure is:

```
parent A
  -child B
   - - child c
  ---child d
----child e
```

the following code can loop out the first layer (-child B). If I want to loop them all out, how do I do it?

```
foreach ($childCatID as $kid)
{
    $childCatName = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT name FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE term_id=$kid");
    echo $childCatName->name;
}
```

if the layer of all the child that in the parent A  is fourth depth, how to loop them out?
If the layer of of all the child that in the parent A is not known, is there a way to loop them out?

I tried with the following code, but not loop them out.

```
foreach ($childCatID as $kidone)
  foreach ($kidone as $kidtwo){
    foreach ($kidtwo as $kidthree){
      foreach ( $kidthree as $kid){
        $childCatName = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT name FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE term_id=$kid");
        echo $childCatName->name;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should package your foreach loop up into a function, and call it recursively

```
function EchoNode($node)
{
    if (is_array($node))
    {
        foreach ($node as $kid)
        {
            if (is_array($kid))
            {
                EchoNode($kid);
            }
            else
            {
                $childCatName = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT name FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE term_id=$kid");
                echo $childCatName->name;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $childCatName = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT name FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE term_id=$node");
        echo $childCatName->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you,when i run your code,there is no any output.i using $node replace with $childCatID